# Two Horizontal RecyclerViews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm building a new app, it has a design that looks like this one:

https://www.jivesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/circle-org-chart.gif

I have created two recyclers communicating to each other, using callbacks.

I have also implemented the vertical scroll effect via onFling methods, but the overall experience is not that much, I'm wondering if there's a better widget to be used in this case other than recyclers?

Comment: What exactly is wrong?

Comment: my implementation isn't perfect, the app is not mature, I was hoping someone would give me a better solution, am willing to start over.